# PHP can't select anything from only one of the mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm having this issue, where only one table just doesn't want to work.

I have a simple php api. All it does is query data from the databases. I have a lot of tables and they are all structured the same. (mostly)
Table name are md_12_201807. But this one doesn't display anything. It works in phpmyadmin, but doesn't when I use the api.

CODE:

```
$ceg = $_GET['ceg'];
$kir = $_GET['kir'];
$ido = $_GET['ido'];
$return = array();
$q = "SELECT * FROM `{$ceg}_{$kir}_{$ido}`";
$sq = mysqli_query($server, $q);
  switch ($ceg) {
    case 'md':
      while ($sqa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sq)) {
        $temp = array(
          'id'=> $sqa['id'],
          'cegnev'=> $sqa['cegnev'],
          'projekt_vezeto'=> $sqa['projekt_vezeto'],
          'projekt_ertekesito'=> $sqa['projekt_ertekesito']
        );
        array_push($return, $temp);
      }
```

....

```
if (isAuth && $sq) {
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset= utf-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept");
    echo json_encode($return,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
```

It does work, for all other tables, but this one. In the admin I looked at it but there is nothing strange, it looks just like the others.

Anyone seen something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. It wasn't related to any of this. It was a character that was encoded in something that utf8 didn't have. weird